# Different return and declared function type result, With Strict Mode Off

Tags: vb.net, csla

i have a project which runs with strict mode off and this code.

```
Public Overloads Function Save() As Child
     Return MyBase.Save()
End Function
```

Upon turning strict mode on, an error displays:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Parent' to
>   'Child'.

My question is the parent's save that is being executed OR the child's as the parent's object is being cast to the child's type?

Long Version with all the details:

I am trying to understand what this code exactly does to reproduce it clearly in the VB, so it can be clearly ported to C#.

The project is using CSLA, there is a base object, which is inherited from the Parent of the child. Child inherits Parents which inherits Base.

There is Insert at both the child & the parent. Are both of those called, by that weird difference of the return object and the function's type?

Comment: What is your question? You know what `MyBase` does?

Comment: Need more info.  How is the class declared?  What are the possible targets in the base class?

Comment: I don't understand if the above code results in running the paren't save or the child's. Does it cast the return type to parent's or the reverse? What is the result of the code and why? Is the Type of the function before the return of the result or the opposite?

Comment: Tried to rephrase myself @TimSchmelter

Comment: Assuming that `Child` in the name of a class that inherits from a class called `Parent`, then `MyBase.Save` is calling the `Save` method in `Parent`. The error message tells us that method returns an instance of `Parent` which the `Save` method you posted is attempting to convert to a `Child` in order to return it.

Comment: Correct assumption @Blackwood . Tried to keep my specifics simple, to be more clear and used those names, but i should also state the inheritance clearly.

Comment: @vfle If you can't answer the last sentence in your question, it's an indication that the code needs to be rewritten to make it's intent clear and unambiguous. This is in no way intended to be an insult or attack. Unclear code is just a bear trap waiting for whoever needs to look at it in 6 months (or years).

Comment: That is what i'm doing exactly! Porting from VB to C# and preparing it. But i need to understand what it does before i port it. @TerryCarmen

Comment: @vfile Cool. I just wanted to make sure you weren't trying to fix it so you could leave it there. 8-). I've done maintenance for decades and those kind of things only get scarier as they build up cruft that depends on them.

Comment: As I think about this more, I'm very curious about why this even exists.  Is the only purpose to get back a `Child` instead of a `Parent`?  As presented, I'd argue that the method should be deleted entirely and the client code should be fixed.

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug, you can't in general expect the base class to properly save a derived class object. It is going to miss the fields/properties that were added in the Child class. The Save() method must be `Overridable` so the Child class can write its own implementation.  No point in making it a Function, you already have the object reference.  It is `Me`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to have `Parent` subclass `Csla.BusinessBase`, and then have `Child` subclass `Parent`, you need to implement `Parent` like this:

```
Public Class Parent(Of T)
    Inherits BusinessBase(Of Parent(Of T))

End Class

Public Class Child
    Inherits Parent(Of Child)

    Protected Overrides Function SaveAsync(forceUpdate As Boolean, userState As Object, isSync As Boolean) As Task(Of Parent(Of Child))
        Return MyBase.SaveAsync(forceUpdate, userState, isSync)
    End Function
End Class
```

This allows the generic type `T` to flow from up through the inheritance hierarchy such that the implementation of `SaveAsync` (or `Save` in older versions of CSLA) is of type `Child`.

Answer (score 2):

The Child's save function is called, but the `MyBase` keyword within that function invokes the parent function. It seems the parent version of the `Save()` function has a return type of `Parent`. So it's as if you had this code:

```
Public Overloads Function Save() As Child
    Dim result As Parent = MyBase.Save()
    Return result
End Function
```

It's not allowed to return an object of one type, when a function is declared to return a different type... unless, as the error message tells you, there is an implicit conversion defined between the two types. *Inheritance does not guarantee that conversion.*

Mismatched returns can cause things to blow up at runtime. *This kind of thing is exactly why you should always have Option Strict On*. It will help you do a better job getting inheritance types right.

Presumably, when `Child` inherits `Parent`, it adds its own fields, properties, or methods. At least, that's the usual reason for inheritance. So now you attempt to return an object without any of that extra stuff to a caller that doesn't know it's missing. That's a recipe for disaster.

You can sort-of fix this by adding a `Cast()` to the code above, but because of the issues described here it might be better to re-write this to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: +1 For the option strict on, in my case it's inherited library of VB that i'm trying to convert to C#, thus why i'm facing code i cannot test & understand clearly. But your code returns a parent object like mine, i think you missed a conversion.

Comment: No, that code isn't supposed to work. It's there to demonstrate why things are broken.

Comment: If you're trying to do return type covariance like this, the best approach is sometimes the "curiously recurring template pattern" where the base class is a generic that takes a class parameter constrained to inherit from the base.  Then the `Save` method can return `T` (which is `Child` in the context of the derived class) instead of `Parent`.

Comment: Interestingly enough @craig, that's exactly how CSLA's base classes work. So it is puzzling to me that the OP is having this issue - unless they are using multiple inheritance without following the correct convention to flow the generic type to each subclass.